# Javamelody report sort

Tags: java, eclipse, java-melody

i use javamelody to export report.  i want the report to be downloaded with times being sorted by the Highest mean time above so that it is easier to make sense of what is taking more time during execution. is there any available configuration to enable report PDF downloaded with one of the columns having sorted values?